# How to change prefix key of tmux to Ctrl?

Tags: tmux

I'd like to change prefix key of tmux from C-b to Ctrl only and tried following in .tmux.conf. But it doesn't work.

```
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C
bind C send-prefix
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained [in another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187407/set-ctrlshift-as-prefix-in-tmux) at Unix Stack Exchange, this can't be done:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> are modifiers. These keys aren't transmitted to applications running in a terminal. Rather, when you press something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, this sends a character or a character sequence at the time you press the <kbd>A</kbd> key.